# Create and define functions to apply to different segments/filters that exist (Instead of doing one very long SQL query)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to come up with some arithmetic calculations for some survey data. I want to do these calculations for a number of segments and want to figure out how to do it without writing numerous SELECT statements.

This is what I have so far:

1. **FACT table**. This tables holds survey data at a respondent level - for example, if a survey had 10 questions, this table will have 11 columns: a column to identify the respondent_ID and 10 other columns to identify the responses to those questions.
2. **DIMENSION table**. This table segments we want to view the survey data by at a respondent level - for example, if we want to view survey responses by membership_status and age_bracket, this table will have 3 columns: a column to identify the respondent_ID, and two columns to identify membership_status and age_bracket.
3. **OUTPUT**.
   I want to get aggregate calculations to summarizes the responses to the survey overall and to each question. I also want to be able to get this information for all possible segments that exist in the DIMENSIONS table.

I can do the query below, however I'll need to do this for every segment:

```sql
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN f.QUESTION_1 IN ('8', '9', '10') THEN f.RESPONDENT_ID END))*1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN f.QUESTION_1 IS NOT NULL THEN f.RESPONDENT_ID END))*1.0 AS CSAT_1
FROM FACT f
JOIN DIMENSION d ON f.RESPONDENT_ID = d.RESPONDENT_ID
WHERE d.MEMBERSHIP_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

The calculation above gives us something called a top 3 box. That is just one calculation, I will need to do many of them. Additionally, ever calculation will need to be done for each segment. In order to get a calculation for nonactive members, I would need to run another query and set d.MEMBERSHIP_STATUS = 'INACTIVE' and I would need to run another query with no filter, to get the overall calculation.

Is there a way I could store all my arithmetic calculations needed in my output as a function (maybe in a temp table or something) - my thought is that it'll be better to set the functions somewhere, and then when I need to calculate the output, I would some how call the function to do all the calculations I need, and give me all the calculations for every segment I have?

I can't fully envision how to get there, or if this is even a good solution, so guidance and detailed SQL code would be extremely helpful.Examples please!

Comment: Have a look at grouping sets https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS they might be what you are after

Comment: Are there examples you could provide by any change? I don't think the ones on the link are quite what I want to do.